# "Invalid Request" error when checking launched programs

Tags: vbscript, wmi-query

I wanted to write a program that checks every 15 minutes if  amount of programs is launched like (toto1.bat, toto2.bat,toto3.bat, iexplore.exe …) whether it finds nothing so it launch it.

This my draft script trying to reach my aim, but I have an "Invalid Request" error in line 31.

```
Option Explicit
Dim ProcessPath1,ProcessPath2,ProcessPath3,ProcessPath4
ProcessPath1 = "c:\toto1.bat"
ProcessPath2 = "c:\toto2.bat"
ProcessPath3 = "c:\toto3.bat"
ProcessPath4 = "%ProgramFiles%\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"
'Quitter si le script est déjà lancé
'If AppPrevInstance() = True Then WScript.Quit
'**************************************************************************
'Une boucle Do...Loop avec une pause de 15 minutes
Do
    Call CheckProcess(DblQuote(ProcessPath4))
    Call CheckProcess(DblQuote(ProcessPath1))
    Call CheckProcess(DblQuote(ProcessPath2))
    Call CheckProcess(DblQuote(ProcessPath3))
    Call Pause(15) 'Pause de 15 minutes
Loop
'**************************************************************************
Sub CheckProcess(ProcessPath)
    Dim strComputer,objWMIService,colProcesses,WshShell,Tab,ProcessName,MyCommandLine
    strComputer = "."
    Tab = Split(ProcessPath,"\")
    ProcessName = Tab(UBound(Tab))
    ProcessName = Replace(ProcessName,Chr(34),"")
    MyCommandLine = "cmd /c "& DblQuote(ProcessPath) &""
    MsgBox "ProcessName : " & ProcessName & vbCrLf & "CommandLine : " _
        & MyCommandLine,vbInformation,"CheckProces"
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
        & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
    Set colProcesses = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
        ("Select * from Win32_Process Where Name like '%" & ProcessName _
        & "%' or CommandLine like '%" & MyCommandLine & "%'")
    If colProcesses.Count = 0 Then
        Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        WshShell.Run ProcessPath
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End if
End Sub
'**************************************************************************
'Fonction pour ajouter les doubles quotes dans une variable
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'**************************************************************************
Sub Pause(NMinutes)
    Wscript.Sleep(NMinutes*1000*60)
End Sub
'**************************************************************************
Function AppPrevInstance()
    'Vérifie si un script portant le même nom que le présent script est déjà
    'lancé
    Dim strComputer,objWMIService,colScript,objScript,RunningScriptName,Counter
    strComputer = "."
    Counter = 0
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
        & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
    Set ColScript = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
        ("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name = 'Wscript.exe' OR Name = 'Cscript.exe'")
    For Each objScript In colScript
        RunningScriptName = Mid(objScript.CommandLine, _
            InstrRev(objScript.CommandLine, "\", -1, 1) + 1, _
            Len(objScript.CommandLine) - InstrRev(objScript.CommandLine, "\", -1, 1) - 2)
        If WScript.ScriptName = RunningScriptName Then Counter = Counter + 1
        Wscript.Sleep 10000
    Next
    If Counter > 1 Then
        AppPrevInstance = True
    Else
        AppPrevInstance = False
    End If
    Set colScript = Nothing
    Set objWMIService = Nothing
End Function
'**************************************************************************
```

Comment: Which is line 31? Please try to add a comment after the faulting line, saying "this is the faulting line". If it is the shorter code snippet from entire script, line numbers will differ. Plus, don't make us count.

Comment: Are you sure that you need `DblQuote` while calling `CheckProcess`? The `select` line already has single quotes around it.

Comment: Also, perhaps `ProcessPath4` should be expanded using [ExpandEnvironmentStrings](http://ss64.com/vb/envexpand.html) before checking.

Comment: I mean this line ==> If colProcesses.Count = 0 Then

Comment: ^^ Even I counted to the same line. But no apparent reason for "Invalid Request" error on that line.

Comment: I thnink that
"Count" does not exist on a null object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem like this :

```
Option Explicit
If AppPrevInstance() Then   
    MsgBox "Il y a une instance déjà en cours",VbExclamation,"Il y a une instance déjà en cours"    
    WScript.Quit   
Else   
    Do   
        Call Main(Array("c:\toto1.bat","c:\toto2.bat","c:\toto3.bat","%ProgramFiles%\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"))
        Call Pause(15) 'Pause de 15 minutes
    Loop   
End If   
'**************************************************************************
Sub Main(colProcessPaths)   
    Dim ProcessPath   
    For Each ProcessPath In colProcessPaths     
        CheckProcess(ProcessPath)   
    Next   
End Sub   
'**************************************************************************
Sub CheckProcess(ProcessPath)   
    Dim ProcessName : ProcessName = StripProcPath(ProcessPath)   
    With GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")   
        With .ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Commandline LIKE " &  CommandLineLike(ProcessName))      
            If .Count = 0 Then    
                With CreateObject("WScript.Shell")  
                    .Run DblQuote(ProcessPath) 
                End With    
            Else    
                Exit Sub    
            End if   
        End With   
    End With   
End Sub   
'**************************************************************************
Function AppPrevInstance()   
    With GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")   
        With .ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE CommandLine LIKE " & CommandLineLike(WScript.ScriptFullName) & _
        " AND CommandLine LIKE '%WScript%' OR CommandLine LIKE '%cscript%'")   
            AppPrevInstance = (.Count > 1)   
        End With   
    End With   
End Function   
'**************************************************************************
Sub Pause(Minutes)    
    Wscript.Sleep(Minutes*1000*60)    
End Sub   
'**************************************************************************
Function StripProcPath(ProcessPath)   
    Dim arrStr : arrStr = Split(ProcessPath, "\")   
    StripProcPath = arrStr(UBound(arrStr))   
End Function   
'**************************************************************************
Function CommandLineLike(ProcessPath)   
    ProcessPath = Replace(ProcessPath, "\", "\\")   
    CommandLineLike = "'%" & ProcessPath & "%'"   
End Function
'**************************************************************************
'Fonction pour ajouter les doubles quotes dans une variable
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'**************************************************************************
```

Answer (score 2):

`MyCommandLine` contains backslashes, which are escape characters in WMI queries. Unescaped backslashes in a path make the query invalid, thus resulting in the error you observed.

Replace

```
MyCommandLine = "cmd /c "& DblQuote(ProcessPath) &""
```

with

```
MyCommandLine = "cmd /c "& DblQuote(Replace(ProcessPath, "\", "\\")) &""
```